# Postgres error due to the use of '%' for pattern matching in the parameterized query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a parameterized query to be executed on a Postgres database:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (customer_id) customer_id,
    COALESCE('Terminated') AS note,
    TO_CHAR((DATE_TRUNC('DAY', note_date)), 'YYYY-mm-dd') AS note_date
FROM
    notes
WHERE
    note LIKE 'Terminated.%'
    AND note_date = %s
LIMIT
    1
```

I'm running the query in python:

```
def execute_query(creds, sql_file_path, param1):
    with create_db_conn(creds) as cursor:
        sql_file = open(sql_file_path, "r")
        query = sql_file.read()
        try:
            cursor.execute(query, (param1,))
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as error:
            print(f"Query failed to execute: {error}")
        # Fetch all results
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    return data
```

When I run this query, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/__main__.py", line 64, in execute_query
    cursor.execute(query, (param1,))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The query runs successfully when I remove the pattern match subclause `note LIKE 'Terminated.%'`. How do I fix this error while keeping the pattern match subclause in the query? The [psycopg2 docs](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html#execute-arguments) don't describe alternative placeholders other than %s. Thanks in advance for any input or resources.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `%` using a second `%` symbol in the query like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (customer_id) customer_id,
    COALESCE('Terminated') AS note,
    TO_CHAR((DATE_TRUNC('DAY', note_date)), 'YYYY-mm-dd') AS note_date
FROM
    notes
WHERE
    note LIKE 'Terminated.%%'
    AND note_date = %s
LIMIT
    1
```

Also the psycopg2 docs address this:

> The typical example is with single quotes in strings: in SQL single
> quotes are used as string literal delimiters, so the ones appearing
> inside the string itself must be escaped, whereas in Python single
> quotes can be left unescaped if the string is delimited by double
> quotes.